# PHPMYADMIN not found (Homebrew, BigSur, with M1 CHIP)

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, homebrew

i'm quite new in mac, and trying to install phpmyadmin in it

i've edited my httpd.conf as instructed

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /opt/homebrew/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /opt/homebrew/share/phpmyadmin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

and comment #Alias /phpmyadmin /opt/homebrew/share/phpmyadmin, caused if not commented `apachetl configtest` will error.

I've enabled my php lib module ini httpd.conf and tested with localhost/info.php, everything just work fine.

What should i do so my phpmyadmin accessible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking view times,
i've found the answer

I need to enable alias module in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
```

and uncomment Alias config for phpmyadmin in my httpd.con

my config before

```
#LoadModule alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
#Alias /phpmyadmin /opt/homebrew/share/phpmyadmin
    <Directory /opt/homebrew/share/phpmyadmin/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

my config now

```
LoadModule alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so

Alias /phpmyadmin /opt/homebrew/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /opt/homebrew/share/phpmyadmin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

and phpmyadmin installed via homebrew run well in my bigsur with m1 chip